# Azure DataFactory create folder dynamically and create json file

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a scenario in which, through datafactory a folder must be created dynamically, which implies that its name must be generated dynamically, this folder is created inside a root folder, once this folder is created, then create a couple of Json files in it, but I can't figure out how to do it.

[image]

The idea is to generate the json files from sql server and through datafactory consult these files and load them in the folder once it is created.

I think it can be done by copy activity but i am literally stuck and i don't know what to do

any ideas?...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a folder separately. We can specify folder name in directory field of Sink dataset. If the specified folder does not exist, a folder will be created, and file will be copied to it.

**Please follow below steps:**

**Step1**: add source to Azure data factory

[image: Ref1]

**Step2**: Create Set variable `Add name` and `Value`.

[image: Ref2]

**Step3**: Go to sink add Storage account and select Json format.

**Step4**: Open Json file  -> Add parameter name and string type -> connection add dynamic Contant.

[image: ref3]

[image: Ref4]

[image: Ref5]

**Step5**: Go to Sink, you will find Parameter name and add dynamic content of Set variable.

[image: Ref6]

**This is the output of Storage account.**

[image: Ref7]

> **Note:** Edit the value for `set variable` activity to give required dynamic name ( I used `'output'` as value for demonstration) for your
> output folder.

Comment: Thank you very much @BhanunagasaiVamsi, the test I just carried out was successful, however with this I can create a single Json file, the idea is to be able to create two files, any ideas?

Thanks again for the valuable teaching.